# Can not access Admin stie

Tags: magento2.2.4

Whenever I go to my admin site I get:
**There has been an error processing your request**
Class ******\Testing\Controller\Router does not exist

I have checked the logs, I have redeployed and changed permissions but no luck

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: add file code..

Answer (score 0):

I think is error is coming from one of your custom module.

You should check ********\Testing\Controller\Router** files namespace and code.

If I am not wrong and this is your custom module then check in app/code/[Your_module_name]/Testing/Controller/**Router.php**

There should be some syntax mistake that you have to find and repair.

Thank you
Hiren Patel